# Does this "born of Jove" statement mean what I think it does?

Tags: grammar

> You are a man of such strength and subtlety! You could have been born of Jove!!

I wrote this, but does this mean:

> *"Wow you are strong and shrewd! It wouldn't amaze me if you told me you were Jove's offspring."*

Comment: The only thing is that "subtle" doesn't mean "shrewd," but I don't think you were verifying meaning and usage here, just grammar, correct?

Comment: @CocoPop Actually, "subtle" can have a subtle meaning that is very close to shrewd. The entry for "subtle" in the Oxford Dictionaries Online list under meanings 1.2 and 1.3 ["Making use of clever and indirect methods to achieve something" and "Capable of making fine distinctions"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/subtle). If someone has these traits, one could argue that they are ["Having or showing sharp powers of judgment; astute"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shrewd), which is the meaning of shrewd.

Comment: @Egghead99: I see that now. When I read this, I didn't realize she was citing something so dated - I though it was meant to be modern English. Thanks!

Comment: @CocoPop Sure thing! It may seem a tad nit-picky, but since this is English Language *Learners*, we should always keep in mind that our "students" may be using uncommon (but linguistically correct) meanings of words that they learned in older dictionaries. Without the luxury of growing up in an English-speaking country, ESL students often take dictionary definitions at face value and are excited to try out all of the different meanings of a new word, especially when they haven't yet learned other words that we natives would deem more "acceptable".

Answer (score 1):

That is absolutely correct. I don't know if you're questioning a specific part of your sentence, but grammatically it's spot on.

Comment: So this "wouldn't amaze" nuance is also spot on?

Comment: Yes it is - you paraphrased it very well. Good work! :))

Comment: There is also the astrological interpretation, instead of the demigod interpretation.  "Born of Jove" could mean "born under the astrological influence of Jupiter".